# Variable not getting updated while using redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I am creating a simple movie website. I have a page through which user can edit the movie details (like movie_name, movie_cast etc...). I am using redux toolkit to manage state. Here is the `EditDetails.js` page where user can edit details:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { useParams } from 'react-router'
import Loading from '../components/Loading'
import { updateMovie, getMovieData } from "../redux/EditMovieSlice"

function EditMovie() {
    const { movie_id } = useParams()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getMovieData(movie_id))
    }, [])

    let { isLoading, movie_name, movie_image, movie_cast, movie_description, movie_favorite } = useSelector(state => state.addMovie)
    console.log(movie_name)//this is getting logged even after reloading
    let [movieName, setMovieName] = useState(movie_name)
    let [movieImage, setmovieImage] = useState(movie_image)
    let [movieCast, setmovieCast] = useState(movie_cast)
    let [movieDescription, setmovieDescription] = useState(movie_description)
    let [movieFavorite, setmovieFavorite] = useState(movie_favorite)

    if (isLoading) {
        return <Loading />
    }

    const submitMovie = () => {
        const date = new Date()
        const month = date.getMonth() + 1
        const todayDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + date.getDay()

        let movieObject = {
            movie_name: movieName,
            movie_image: movieImage,
            movie_cast: movieCast,
            movie_description: movieDescription,
            movie_favorite: movieFavorite,
            movie_create_date: todayDate,
        }

        dispatch(updateMovie(movieObject))
    }

    return (
        <div className='add-movie-container'>
            <div className='add-movie-container-form'>
                <label>Movie Name </label>
                <input type="text" value={movieName} onChange={(event) => setMovieName(event.target.value)} />
                <label>Movie Image </label>
                <input type="text" value={movieImage} onChange={(event) => setmovieImage(event.target.value)} />
                <label>Movie Cast </label>
                <input type="text" value={movieCast} onChange={(event) => setmovieCast(event.target.value)} />
                <label>Movie Description </label>
                <input type="text" value={movieDescription} onChange={(event) => setmovieDescription(event.target.value)} />
                <label>Movie Favorite </label>
                <input type="text" value={movieFavorite} onChange={(event) => setmovieFavorite(event.target.value)} />
                <button onClick={() => submitMovie()}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default EditMovie
```

The above component contains a form through which the current details are displayed. However when I click the reload button, the details go away even though I am able to log the values for some variables. The value for the variables are present but they are not appearing in the forms.

Here is the slice for the same:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    isLoading: true,
    movie_name: "",
    movie_image: "",
    movie_cast: "",
    movie_description: "",
    movie_favorite: "",
    movie_create_date: ""
}

const editMovieSlice = createSlice({
    name: "addMovie",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        getMovieData: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = true
        },
        loadMovie: (state, action) => {
            
            state.isLoading = false
            state.movie_name = action.payload.movie_name
            state.movie_image = action.payload.movie_image
            state.movie_cast = action.payload.movie_cast
            state.movie_description = action.payload.movie_description
            state.movie_favorite = action.payload.movie_favorite
            state.movie_create_date = action.payload.movie_create_date
        },
        setMovieData: (state, action) => {
            // state.isLoading = false
            // state.movie_name = action.payload.movie_name
            // state.movie_image = action.payload.movie_image
            // state.movie_cast = action.payload.movie_cast
            // state.movie_description = action.payload.movie_description
            // state.movie_favorite = action.payload.movie_favorite
            // state.movie_create_date = action.payload.movie_create_date

        },
        updateMovie: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = true
        },
        updateDone: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = false
        }
    }
})

export const { setMovieData, getMovieData, updateMovie, loadMovie } = addMovieSlice.actions
export default addMovieSlice.reducer
```

Here is the saga for doing asynchronous calls:

```
export function* setMovieData() {
    yield takeEvery("addMovie/getMovieData", getMovie)
}
```

The above function is registered with `createSagaMiddleware()` object:

```
const addMovieSaga = createSagaMiddleware()
.
.
.
//other settings

.
.
.
addMovieSaga.run(setMovieData)
```

Here is the `getMovie()` function:

```
function* getMovie(action) {
    let url = READ_SINGLE_MOVIE_URL + action.payload
    let movie = yield fetch(url)
    movie = yield movie.json()
    yield put(loadMovie(movie))
}
```

Please comment if more information is needed.

I tried to log the information of the variables(like movie_name) and was getting the answer, but the same value is not getting reflected in the form

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this section of the code:

```
let { isLoading, movie_name, movie_image, movie_cast, movie_description, movie_favorite } = useSelector(state => state.addMovie)
let [movieName, setMovieName] = useState(movie_name)
...etc...
```

When you do this: `let [movieName, setMovieName] = useState(movie_name)` the `movie_name` value from redux is used to set the initial state only.  It will not respond to changes in the redux data.

On the first render of this component, the movie has not yet been loaded so all of your initial states will be empty.

---

One simple solution is to delay the mounting of the Edit component until you know that the movie has been loaded.

Break your current code up into two nested components.

```
// We load the movie here.
function EditMovie() {
    const { movie_id } = useParams()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getMovieData(movie_id))
    }, [movie_id]) // The movie id needs to be a dependency.

    const { isLoading, ...movie } = useSelector(state => state.addMovie)
    
    if (isLoading) {
        return <Loading />
    }

    // Handle any cases where the movie object was not loaded, such as API errors.
    if (!movie.movie_name) {
        return null
    }

    // Render the edit form once we have a movie.
    return (
        <EditMovieForm movie={movie}/>
    )
}

// We only render this once we have data.
function EditMovieForm({ movie }) {
    const { movie_name, movie_image, movie_cast, movie_description, movie_favorite } = movie

    let [movieName, setMovieName] = useState(movie_name)
    let [movieImage, setmovieImage] = useState(movie_image)
    let [movieCast, setmovieCast] = useState(movie_cast)
    let [movieDescription, setmovieDescription] = useState(movie_description)
    let [movieFavorite, setmovieFavorite] = useState(movie_favorite)

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const submitMovie = () => {
        const date = new Date()
        const month = date.getMonth() + 1
        const todayDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + date.getDay()

        let movieObject = {
            movie_name: movieName,
            movie_image: movieImage,
            movie_cast: movieCast,
            movie_description: movieDescription,
            movie_favorite: movieFavorite,
            movie_create_date: todayDate,
        }

        dispatch(updateMovie(movieObject))
    }

    return (
        <div className='add-movie-container'>
            <div className='add-movie-container-form'>
                <label>Movie Name </label>
                <input type="text" value={movieName} onChange={(event) => setMovieName(event.target.value)} />
                <label>Movie Image </label>
                <input type="text" value={movieImage} onChange={(event) => setmovieImage(event.target.value)} />
                <label>Movie Cast </label>
                <input type="text" value={movieCast} onChange={(event) => setmovieCast(event.target.value)} />
                <label>Movie Description </label>
                <input type="text" value={movieDescription} onChange={(event) => setmovieDescription(event.target.value)} />
                <label>Movie Favorite </label>
                <input type="text" value={movieFavorite} onChange={(event) => setmovieFavorite(event.target.value)} />
                <button onClick={() => submitMovie()}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default EditMovie
```